# Query table based on results of another table

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a query in Access that picks out rows in a table based on the existence of values in another table. I am looking at a table that contains the state of different ID numbers and checking that for whatever state that ID is at it has progressed through the lower states.

For example, Each ID goes from apprentice to journeyman to master. If an ID is at master, as noted in the State table, there should be a record in the Events table for that ID being at apprentice and master as well.

The query should return the IDs from the State table that are at the Master state but have not properly progressed through the states based on the entries in the Events table.

With the two tables below, the query should return IDs 2. ID 2 is listed at Master but never was at the Journeyman state.

State Table:

`ID  Status
1   Master
2   Master
3   Apprentice
4   Journeyman`

Events Table:

`Date  Status  ID
7/25/17  Master  1
7/25/17  Master  2
7/24/17  Journeyman  1
7/24/17  Journeyman  3
7/20/17  Apprentice  4
7/20/17  Apprentice  3
7/20/17  Apprentice  2
7/20/17  Apprentice  1`

I have created a query to look for IDs marked as Master. But I'm not sure where to go from there to look at the Events table for IDs marked as Master in the State table.

This is my simple query. This is my first time really using Access, any pointers would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If no Journeyman is the only event criteria then consider:

`SELECT * FROM State WHERE Status="Master" AND NOT ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Events WHERE Status="Journeyman");`

Date is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names. Better would be EventDate.